# Backwards search string

Tags: regex, search, vim

Does anyone know how to create a backwards search string using `match()`?

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
            ^
```

(`^` = cursor position)

I want to find the start and end column of the word before the cursor (word2).

I tried this regex without success:

```
match(getline('.'), '?\w\ze\s', col('.')-1)
```

Does `?` not work in a string to search backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the normal command `?` with the function `match()` which works on strings. What you are actually looking for is the `searchpos()` function which searches for some pattern in the buffer and gives you back the position.

```
let [start_line, start_col] = searchpos('\<\w\+\>', 'bn')
let [end_line, end_col] = searchpos('\<\w\+\>', 'bne')
```

The flags mean the following:

- `b` backwards
- `n` don't move the cursor
- `e` use the end of the match as the returned position

Please see the following for more information:

```
:h search(
:h searchpos(
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried searchpos(). I noted that it doesn't recognize characters as [èéìòù] if this character is at the end of a word (same problem with search()). That's why I switched to match()/matchend().

Comment: You can use character class. e.g. `[[:alnum:]_]\+`. See `:h /[]` for more information.